Translating query using LAG function from SQL Server to BigQuery
I had a working query on SQL Server which resulted in a table with columns having CPI values lagged and also one column having updated values every 6 months with a 4 month lag.
SELECT   *
        ,LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
        ,LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
        ,LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
        ,LAG (CPI, ((MONTH+8) % 6) + 4) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4

FROM SYSTEM_CPI

System_CPI table is a table having cpi values for each year, month [YEAR | MONTH | CPI]
When trying to do the same query in BigQuery, the LAG function will not accept the MONTH column as parameter. So the query gives an error. Is there an easy workaround for this?
DESIRED OUTPUT:



As per the question guide, please do not use images. For data use table markdown. 2) Please don't ask questions about translating code - because that requires an expert in both domains, and that they correctly interpret your requirements. Instead provide your full requirements using a [mre]. The query in a different language can be provided as supporting data, not the actual data. And only tag the technology you want the solution in.


Also include what your research has shown up, when you a) checking the official documentation for the technology you want a solution in. and b) searched the internet for related problems.

as per documentation offset must be a non-negative integer literal or parameter. see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lag i.e. it does NOT accept an expression which is what you have attempted to do. So, no "easy workaround".

nb. in TSQL the offset is documated as offset The number of rows back from the current row from which to obtain a value. If not specified, the default is 1. offset can be a column, subquery, or other expression that evaluates to a positive integer or can be implicitly converted to bigint. offset cannot be a negative value or an analytic function.  so it is much more adaptable.

Thanks everyone for your responses. Very clear explanation of what I was doing wrong.

You may have to break-up your query into several unioned sub-queries to get around the restrictions of the offset which must be a  a non-negative integer literal or parameter. refer
The formula ((MONTH+8) % 6) + 4 where month must be in range 1 to 12 gives a fixed result range of 4 to 9 like so:
select
  month, ((MONTH+8) % 6) + 4
from (
    select 1  as month union all select 2  as month union all select 3  as month union all select 4  as month union all
    select 5  as month union all select 6  as month union all select 7  as month union all select 8  as month union all
    select 9  as month union all select 10 as month union all select 11 as month union all select 12 as month
     ) x
order by 2, 1




month
(No column name)




4
4


10
4


5
5


11
5


6
6


12
6


1
7


7
7


2
8


8
8


3
9


9
9



fiddle
So arrange the sub-queries so that the offset can be an integer literal by using where clauses that choose the months to suit the needed offset.
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 4) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (4,10)
UNION ALL
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 5) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (5,11)
UNION ALL
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 6) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (6,12)
UNION ALL
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 7) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (1,7)
UNION ALL
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 8) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (2,8)
UNION ALL
SELECT
      *
    , LAG (CPI, 1) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_1
    , LAG (CPI, 2) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_2
    , LAG (CPI, 3) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_3
    , LAG (CPI, 9) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH ASC) AS CPI_6M_LAG4
FROM SYSTEM_CPI
WHERE MONTH IN (3,9)
ORDER BY Year, Month


Thanks a lot for your response! Will have to expand the code
